# Communication with JADE from non-JADE application

Tags: java, agents-jade

Is it possible to send a message to (and receive from) a JADE agent/platform from a non-JADE application (written in Java or C/C++)? Is it somehow possible to send an HTTP Post request to the platform that contains a FIPA compliant ACL message? 
I could establish a socket connection but I'm sure that's not the best option, right?

I've read about JadeGateway but don't really get it to work and don't understand why I should use it if I need the Jade libs anyway with which I could simply run another platform.

Would be nice if someone could help me out here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three are three options I can think of, you can use JNI, JMS or web services. With JNI you would make native calls into the C/C++ code, JMS you would send a message to a queue that had a listener capable of calling the C/C++ or with web services you could invoke a web service call that would call the C/C++ code on the other side (as in Java/.Net integration via ws).

Comment: Found some time to look into that. Followed the PtP example from here: [link](http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/). Running into `NoInitialContextException` caused by not specifying an `InitialContext`. That's where it gets tricky for me. Do I have to write my own Context? If so, how do I do that, what does it need, etc? Is there any default class I could use?

Comment: You should just be able to write: `InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();`

Did you look at their example [link](http://www.novell.com/documentation/extend52/Docs/help/MP/jms/tutorial/)

Comment: Yea I did. And if I use just that then I get the said exception saying that I need to specify the class name. i.e, the property value for `java.naming.factory.initial`. And I have no idea what class to use there.

Comment: Are you including the jar file that contains InitialContext in your classpath?

Comment: I wasn't running a server that offered JMS. After setting up a wildfly server it worked flawlessly.

Comment: Hey @Ricky can you link some source code? Starting a project that would really benefit from seeing how you set this up :)

Comment: Hello @JordanMackie, I'm sorry but I don't have the sources anymore.